# Limited Access to Domain Controller for Active Directory Administration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, remote-access

I have to provide a group Jr. Sys Admins limited access to a domain controller for the purpose of limited Active Directory User and Group administration (i.e. user creation, password reset, etc.) I have implemented delegation to limit the scope of tasks the Jr. Sys Admins may execute on the Active Directory. Some of these users use macOS, so using Remote Server Administration Tools like one might use on a Windows machine is not an option for them.

As such I would like to give them RDP access to a domain controller. I'd like them to be able to open Active Directory Users and Computers (without prompting for administrator credentials) but limit their access to the remainder of the system as much as possible. Note: I may need to give them access to a few other items for other related job responsibilities.

- What is the best way to accomplish this?
- If imposing restrictions via Group Policy is the best method, what is the most efficient way to construct a policy that would accomplish my stated objective?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to achieve the desired results through a combination of configurations.

1. Created OU for "Limited AD Administrators"
2. Created a first user account in above captioned OU
3. On my "Company Users" OU I delegated access to the user account for: create, delete, manage user accounts, reset passwords, read all user information.
4. On my "Company Groups" OU I delegated access to the user account for: modify the membership of a group.
5. On Domain Controller, in Local Security Policy > User Rights Management > Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services: added the user account.
6. Added the user to the "Backup Operators" built-in group. This provides sufficient privilege to open Active Directory Users and Computers.
7. Created a GPO and linked it to the "Limited AD Administrators" OU with the following restrictions:

Run only specified Windows Applications: dsa.msc, mmc.exe

Prevent access to the command prompt

Prevent access to registry editing tools

Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep and Hibernate commands

Comment: The `Backup Operators` membership may break permissions on those users due to [AdminSDHolder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx#id0250013). It also seems like a bad idea to let them login to the DC directly. I get that you have Mac users who can't run native tools locally. But why not setup a separate "workstation" VM for them to login to?

Comment: @RyanBolger I agree that it is less than ideal. Hence, so much effort to lock the accounts down to such a limited set of actions on the directory and the system. Unfortunately, I am trying to meet the specification of a client, despite my disagreement with the fundamental idea. Workstation on LAN with RSAT installed that user could RDP into would be the better option. This is simply the best technical solution I could come up with to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Gotcah. Clients can be a pain.

Comment: By giving them "Backup Operators" you have effectively given them administrator access to the entire domain. I'm not sure whether the GPO restrictions you've put in place will effectively block use of that access or not.  I've figured out a safer way to bypass the problem with MMC, see my answer.

Comment: Please elaborate on how giving “Backup Operator” privleges is “effectively giving (sic) them administrator access to the entire domain” - I’m not sure I understand that assessment.

Comment: If you have backup privilege and access to run arbitrary applications, this is more or less straightforward: use your backup privilege to replace `qmgr.dll` with a malicious executable, then use `bitsadmin /list` to start the BITS service.  That gives you local system on the DC, and you can then add yourself to Domain Admins, or just do whatever you like from local system.

Comment: ... your group policy settings will make this more difficult, but I'm not sure that they'll make it impossible.  For example, the "Run only specified Windows Applications" setting only applies to Explorer, you may be able to bypass it.  If I get time later on I'll set up a test machine with the same policies and see what I can find.  But there are other possibilities, e.g., I'm not sure whether or not you can leverage backup privilege over the network.

Comment: When I attempted to reproduce your setup, adding the user to "Backup Operators" didn't solve the problem - trying to run Active Directory Users and Computers still resulted in a UAC elevation dialog.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not having much luck so far at breaking through Group Policy, not that I'm an expert or anything.  You will need to set the "Prohibit New Task Creation" Group Policy or the user can launch arbitrary applications via the Task Scheduler.  (The application whitelist unfortunately doesn't restrict which MMC snap-ins you can use.)  I was able to launch IE too, but found that it was surprisingly thorough in blocking me from doing anything particularly bad.

Comment: There are other potential risks - e.g., a malicious printer driver, or a malicious MMC snapin, but that's probably getting well beyond your threat model.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have gradually added restrictions via Group Policy as I've encountered opportunities for someone to get their hands on things they shouldn't be on. One of the most obvious and glaring ones was to restrict access in Explorer. You are correct my threat model is fairly limited. I just don't want an overzealous Jr. Sys Admin to try and do too much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main problem is safely giving the user access to the Active Directory Users and Computers tool, which on a Domain Controller (and *only* on a Domain Controller) requests UAC elevation when you try to run it.  I believe this to be a bug or unintended feature in Windows, apparently caused by membership in the "Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Alias" domain local group resulting in a split token during logon.

So one possible solution would be to change the membership of that group, but I'm not sure what the side-effects of that might be.  So instead I recommend disabling UAC elevation [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887), i.e., by setting the environment variable `__compat_layer` to `RunAsInvoker` for the users in question.

This causes Windows to ignore the fact that `mmc.exe` is configured to request elevation if the user has a split token, and just runs it without any elevated privileges.

Note that the variable name begins with two underscores, not just one.

*EDIT:* setting the environment variable via Group Policy doesn't work; it looks like there's some sort of special treatment for environment variable names beginning with an underscore.  You'll need an application or script to set it for you.

Or you could turn UAC off, though I'm not sure what side-effects that might have.